# Wrong ruby version, can't install rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a dedicated server and many of php projects on it.
I recently asked it support to install Ruby there.

They've installed Ruby 2.5.3 and gave me code for .profile file:

> $ PATH=/opt/ruby-2.5.3/bin:/home/users/rails/.gems/bin:$PATH $ export
>
> GEM_PATH=/home/users/rails/.gems $ export
>
> GEM_HOME=/home/users/rails/.gems

I'm in /home/users/rails location and when i write ruby -v, it shows me still 1.x version.
Before i ask administration, is there way to run ruby 2.5.3 when you see those lines?

I've runned "ruby -v" code in paths but it didn't change:

> /home/users/rails/
>
> /home/users/rails/.gems/
>
> /home/users/rails/.gems/bin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what to do with dedicated server support,

i've used "$" in the beginning of the line in .profile file,
removing it fixed the problem